# "Acostado" vs "Acostando"

Tags: verbos, participio, gerundio

In Spanish, we typically translate "I am lying in my bed" to "Estoy acostado en mi cama" whereas "I am singing" is "Estoy cantando" which is the gerundio form of the verb.

I am confused, why do we use participio form for 'Acostarse' while we typically use the gerundio or present simple to express a continuous action.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*[Acostar(se)](https://dle.rae.es/acostar)*" is an action meaning "to go to bed".

It works like "to sing". Once you finish singing you are no longer singing.

So the same happens with "*acostarse*". Once you finish the action you are no longer "*acostándote*" ("going to bed"). But, as a result of that action, you are "*acostado*" ("lying on bed").

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: acostado is to be in bed, not lying on the bed. Lie on a bed is echar(se) en una cama.

Comment: This answer is not right.

Answer (score 4):

This is a distinct difference between English and Spanish.

In English we generally use an adverbial particle (typically *up*, *down*), or use a different verb, to indicate the action through which we reach a certain body position, and no particle to indicate that the person has reached that position. Instead, in Spanish we use the present participle (ending in *-ando*, *-endo*) to indicate the action and the past participle (ending in *-ado*, *-ido*) to indicate the state:

- He's sitt**ing down**. (Se está sent**ando** / Está sent**ándo**se)
- He's sitt**ing** on an armchair. (Está sent**ado** en un sillón)
- He´s stand**ing up**. (Se está par**ando** / Está par**ándo**se)
- He's stand**ing** at the door. (Está par**ado** en la puerta)
- He´s kneel**ing down**. (Se está arrodil**lando** / Está arrodill**ándo**se)
- He's kneel**ing** in front of the monument. (Está arrodil**lado** frente al monumento)
- He's crouch**ing down**. (Se está agach**ando** / Está agach**ándo**se)
- He's crouch**ing** inside the cave. (Está agach**ado** dentro de la cueva)
- He's ly**ing down** / getting into bed. (Se está acost**ando** / Está acost**ándo**se)
- He's ly**ing** on the sofa. (Está acost**ado** en el sofá)

Answer (score 0):

I am **lying** on my bed.

Estoy **echado** en mi cama. Not acostado. from: echar(se) en una cama.

Estoy acostado = I am in bed. acostarse= to go to bed.
Estoy acostandome = I am going to bed. [in the process of going to bed]

Estoy cantando. = I am singing.

Answer (score 0):

Spanish uses "acostado" (lying down) and "sentado" (sitting) and "parado" (standing) as participles instead of gerunds because the idea is that you have fully adopted that position.

"I am standing" says you are taking an action, sustaining the position.

"Estoy parado" says you are in a state, having completed a movement.